# Erro ao listar rotas em um Api Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma api rest usando laravel e para criar essa api estou usando o tutorial:

- https://rafaell-lycan.com/2015/construindo-restful-api-laravel-parte-1/
- https://rafaell-lycan.com/2015/construindo-restful-api-laravel-parte-2/
- https://rafaell-lycan.com/2015/construindo-restful-api-laravel-parte-3/

porem ao rodar o comando:

```
php artisan route:list
```

Me é apresentado o seguinte erro:

```
 ReflectionException:Class App\Http\Controllers\pagesController does not exist

 at /var/www/html/freelance/HQ Alma/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:7 
79
775| if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
776|     return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
777|}
778|
779|$reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
780|
781|// If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
782|// an abstract type such as an Interface of Abstract Class and there is
783|// no binding registered for the abstractions so we need to bail out.

 Exception trace:

 1 ReflectionClass::__construct("App\Http\Controllers\pagesController")
  /var/www/html/freelance/HQ Alma/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779

2 Illuminate\Container\Container::build("App\Http\Controllers\pagesController")
  /var/www/html/freelance/HQ Alma/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:658

Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Minhas rotas são essas:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'hqi'), function()
{

  Route::get('/', function () {
     return response()->json(['message' => 'HQI API', 'status' => 
     'Connected']);;
  });

  Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
  Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController');
  Route::resource('palestra', 'PalestrasDivulgacaoController');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
   return redirect('api');
});
```

Alguem saberia oque pode ser?

Comment: Aparentemente o Laravel não está encontrando a classe `PagesController`. Verifique o nome, local do arquivo e se o `composer.json` está corretamente configurado, não esqueça de dar um `dump-autoload` depois

Comment: PagesController e o controller que criei ele nao tem que tar setado no composer

Comment: eu comecei do zero e fui testando, e de alguma forma o laravel não reconhecia que o controller criado existia, depois de refazer ele aceito de forma correta

Comment: Oque foi apontado no erro é que o controller não foi encontrado. Inicialmente exclui o controller e criei novamente e não funcionou, então criei uma nova api laravel e fui testando o processo parte por parte ate apresentar erro, porem não apresentou erro na criação das rotas de novo

Comment: Você pode tentar executar o comando ```composer dump-autoload``` e ver se o Laravel passa a reconhecer sua rota.